# Not Able to Pass Where Clause in SearchCursor in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, cursor, select-by-attribute

Can you please take a look at this snippet and let me know why I am not able to properly pass the Where Clause ('"[NAME_1]" = Ohio') in SearchCursor?

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

def unique_values(table , field):
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, [field], '"[NAME_1]" = Ohio') as cursor:
    return sorted({row[0] for row in cursor})

uniques = unique_values(r'C:\arcgis\ArcTutor\AAA\src\USA.shp' , 'NAME_2')

for unique in uniques:
    print (unique)
```

I am getting the following RuntimeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<module1>", line 8, in <module>
  File "<module1>", line 7, in unique_values
  File "<module1>", line 7, in <setcomp>
RuntimeError: Unspecified error
```

Same error on this format as well

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, [field], '"NAME_1" = Ohio') as cursor:
```

Comment: Skip the bracers, use "NAME_1 = 'Ohio'" (note the use of double and single quotes). If you're only using one field it doesn't need to be a list, use *with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, field, "NAME_1 = 'Ohio'") as cursor:* and you should reduce your problems. What's the next line about? You're making a dictionary but it's not, there's no key:value pairs, surely you want to do *sorted([row[0] for row in cursor])*?

Comment: @MichaelStimson, OP is using a shapefile. Therefore, the double quotes are necessary.

Comment: @Fezter, no they're not. Try it and see.

Comment: I'd love to, but I don't use shapefiles if I can help it. I'm just looking at the doco [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/addfielddelimiters.htm)

Comment: This is how it shoul like for shapefile "NAME_1" = 'Ohio'

Comment: I understand your aversion to shapefiles @Fezter, I have found that no quote or bracers are required for any of the common storage types when defining a cursor. It may be that some obscure enterprise database needs them but I've not found one yet that complained.

Comment: I agree with @MichaelStimson on this one. I think the need to use AddFieldDelimiters or to use field delimiters evaporated 3-4 dot releases ago for ArcGIS Desktop 10.x and they've never been needed for ArcGIS Pro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wasn't able to replicate your error, but try this:

```
import arcpy    

expression = "NAME_1 = 'Ohio'"

def unique_values(table , field):
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, [field], where_clause=expression) as cursor:
        return sorted({row[0] for row in cursor})

uniques = unique_values(r'C:\arcgis\ArcTutor\AAA\src\USA.shp' , 'NAME_2')

for unique in uniques:
    print (unique)
```

The SearchCursor where_clause parameter takes a SQL string as its input. There are more examples [here](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm)

Answer (score 3):

[Use AddFieldDelimiters](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/addfielddelimiters.htm):

> The field delimiters used in an SQL expression differ depending on the
>   format of the queried data. For instance, file geodatabases and
>   shapefiles use double quotation marks (" "), personal geodatabases use
>   square brackets ([ ]), and enterprise geodatabases don't use field
>   delimiters. The function can take away the guess work in ensuring that
>   the field delimiters used with your SQL expression are the correct
>   ones.

with single quotes around Ohio and three double quotes surrounding everything:

```
sql = """{0} = 'Ohio'""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(table,'NAME_1'))
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table,field,sql) as cursor:
    ...
```

Comment: The problem isn't with the field as specified but with the value, Felix stated it most succinctly, the SQL *definitely* needs a single quote delimiter for a string literal, as the OP had the query stated the SQL was looking to compare NAME_1 field with *a field called Ohio* and not with the *string literal 'Ohio'*.

Comment: @MichaelStimson as the question is currently written i see no indication that Ohio is a field

Comment: And that is the problem, Ohio is not a field but the SQL is looking for it and generating the unspecified error when it can't find the field called Ohio within the table.